# Where to see stdout if I use mod_wsgi to serve application?

Tags: python, django, apache, mod-wsgi, pyramid

Sometimes I need to check the output of a python web apllication.

If I execute the application directly, I can see it from terminal screen.

But I have no idea how to check that for `mod_wsgi`. Will it appear in a seperate log of `apache`? Or do I need to add some codes for `logging`?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `print "message"`, you could use `sys.stderr.write("message")`

For logging to stderr with a [StreamHandler](http://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.handlers.html#streamhandler):

```
import logging
handler = logging.StreamHandler(stream=sys.stderr)
log = logging.getLogger(__name__)
log.setLevel(logging.INFO)
log.addHandler(handler)

log.info("Message")
```

Comment: @AnthonyPerot-Rajan I'm afraid I don't know - I haven't used Pyramid

Answer (score 1):

[wsgilog](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/wsgilog) is simple, and can redirect standard out to a log file automatically for you. Breeze to set up, and I haven't had any real problems with it.

Answer (score 0):

> No WSGI application component which claims to be portable should write to standard output. That is, an application should not use the Python print statement without directing output to some alternate stream. An application should also not write directly to sys.stdout. ([ModWSGI Wiki](http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ApplicationIssues))

So don't... Instead, I recommend using a log aggregation tool like [sentry](https://github.com/getsentry/sentry). It is useful while developing and a must-have in production.